# Site mailboxes when site is created from a custom template

Tags: site, sub-site, site-mailboxes

I'm working on a project management area in Sharepoint (Office 365) at the moment where each new project is a subsite of the main Projects site.
Each project site will include a site mailbox. I've added the site mailbox app to the template and, when I create a new site from this template it works fine. The new site mailbox is created and works as expected.
However, the site mailbox address isn't based on the new site name as I would expect. Normally a site mailbox would be SMO-(sitename)@ourdomain.com but when I create the new site from a template the mail address is coming up as SMO-(random string)@ourdomain.com

I need the users to be able to send email to a uniform address depending on the project number (which is what we use to name the site) and this is making that impossible.

I know that I can add another SMTP address to each site via Powershell but I want the site creation process to be completed by users without my intervention and without them having to run a Powershell script every time.

Thoughts?